# How to query sql with active record for dates between specified times

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, phpactiverecord, active-record-query

I have a database that I want to pull only certain rows that have dates in specified ranges. I'm not sure how to do this properly in active record. Right now it looks like I'm running a standard mysql query inside of an active record query. I hope this gives you the idea of what I'm looking for.

I would also like to be able to get rows with anything before today, including today and 3 days in the future.

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM 'topics_list' . 'topic date' WHERE DATE(order_datetime) BETWEEN '2012-10-01' AND '2012-10-3'");
```

Comment: what is the format you  stored DATE in the database

Answer (score 20, accepted):

this is the way . but according to the DATE format you have in the database you have to change `2012-10-01` and `2012-10-03`

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('topics_list');
$this->db->where('order_datetime <','2012-10-03');
$this->db->where('order_datetime >','2012-10-01');

$result = $this->db->get();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can specify you `$where` and use active records

```
$where = "DATE(order_datetime) BETWEEN '2012-10-01' AND '2012-10-3'";
$this->db->where($where)->get('table_name');
```

Answer (score 3):

```
`$where = array(
  "order_datetime <" => "2012-10-03",
  "order_datetime >" => "2012-10-01"
);
$this->db->select("*")->get_where("topics_list" , $where)`
```

Answer (score 2):

You can specify you $where and use active records

```
$this->db->group_start()
          ->or_where("product_order.generate_date >= ","$start_date")
          ->or_where("product_order.generate_date <","$end_date + INTERVAL 1 DAY")
          ->group_end();
```

Answer (score 1):

To use the "Between" by respecting the Query builder of CI:

```
$this->db->where("order_datetime BETWEEN '2018-10-01' AND '2018-10-3'","", FALSE);
```