# date time comparison codeigniter activer record

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

not able to fetch data from query don't know where i am wrong.

```
public function downloadOrderDailyReport() {
        //$this->load->helper('date');
        $timestamp = date("Y-m-d");
            $this->db->select("O.created, O.paymentMethod,B.SKU as sku, B.name as Bname, B.author as authors, B.edition,B.MRP as mrp, OD.status as order_status");
            $this->db->from("orders AS O");
            $this->db->join("users AS U", 'O.userid=U.id');

            $this->db->join("orderDetail AS OD","O.parentId=OD.orderId",'LEFT');
            $this->db->join("books AS B","OD.bookId=B.id",'LEFT');
            $this->db->where("O.parentId !=", NULL);
            $this->db->where(date('O.created'), $timestamp);
            $query = $this->db->get();

        return $orders = $query && $query->num_rows() ? $query->result() : [];
    }
```

my column date format is - 2018-02-06 14:29:02
i need to compare only today date not time. when remove where date comparison it works fine.

Comment: `$this->db->where('0.created > ', $timestamp);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to query with active record in codeigniter for dates between specified times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102195/how-to-query-with-active-record-in-codeigniter-for-dates-between-specified-times)

Comment: @JamesLalor not working

Comment: @JamesLalor i tried but not working for me

Comment: `$timestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('midnight'));`

Answer (score 0):

Force `O.created` to Date in mysql (note the **quote** emplacement is for `date(O.created)` not only for `O.created`) :

```
$this->db->where('date(O.created)', $timestamp);
```