# How can I convert simple SQL query to CodeIgniter using between?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

Please help me, I want to convert a simple SQL statement to Codeigniter

```
date($fromDate) BETWEEN vehicle_register.start_dt AND vehicle_register.end_dt
```

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: do you want the method chaining query?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102195/how-to-query-sql-with-active-record-for-dates-between-specified-times/12102322#12102322

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this with `Method chaining`,

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('yourTableName');
$this->db->where('date('.$fromDate.') >=', 'vehicle_register.start_dt');
// >= will get conditional date too so please keep it as your reqirement
$this->db->where('date('.$fromDate.') <=', 'vehicle_register.end_dt');
$query= $this->db->get();
if($query->num_rows() > 0){
  //return $query->result();//according to your need
}else{
  //return array();//according to your need
}
```